# Which properties does a critical point have if the Jacobian determinant is $0$ and thus no characteristic equation exists?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, jacobian

I have the system

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
fx'=y(1-x^2-y^2)\\
y'=x-y
\end{array}
\end{equation}

which has several CPs. 5 of them have either of the variables at $0$. This yields a zero-valued determinant for the Jacobian for all these 5 CPs.

Since there is no characteristic equation from the Jacobian at these points, what can be said of these points?

Thanks

Comment: Critical points have $x=y$ from the second equation, thus $x(1-2x^2)=0$ from the first one. These are all simple roots, where did you get 5 points and the singular Jacobian from?

Comment: $x=y=0, x=\pm1, y=\pm1$ and their combinations thereof.

Comment: Check again carefully these points, apart from the first you get not zero in the right sides of both equations.

Comment: How did you get that. I believe you indeed. But if we have trival solution in the first equation, $y=0$ and the second gives $x-y=0$, then so $x=0$

Comment: From the first comment, we have $$\left\{\{x\to 0,y\to 0\},\left\{x\to -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},y\to -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right\},\left\{x\to \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},y\to \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right\}\right\}$$

Comment: Thanks Moo, clearly I didn't combine the information correctly. I will use substitution method next time, as Lutz and you suggest.

Comment: I retried . I get CPs at $(x,y)=\bigg(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}, \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\bigg), \bigg(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}},-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\bigg), \bigg(-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}, \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\bigg), \bigg(-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}},-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\bigg), (0,0) $

Comment: $y'=0$ requires $x=y$ for the critical point. Alternating signs are not possible.

Comment: Yes, thanks for this. I have corrected below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$\begin{align} y(1 - x^2 - y^2) &= 0 \\ x - y &= 0 \end{align}$$

From the second equation

$$y = x$$

Substituting that into the first equation

$$x(1 - 2 x^2) = 0 \implies x = 0, \pm \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Since we know $y = x$, we have three $x$ values and end up with

$$(x, y) = (0,0), \left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right), \left(-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

You can now test these three critical points in the Jacobian.

We can look at a phase portrait and determine their behavior

[image]

Comment: Indeed! If $x=y$, then $x\ne -y$! Sorry, my mistake,

Comment: Beautiful phase portrait. How did you plot it?

Comment: I also added more details so you can continue determining the behaviors of the CPs. The Phase Portrait was done using Mathematica.

Comment: Saddle in the middle and two stable nodes on the sides?

Comment: Yes, so now you can validate that with analyses. You can also plot online using https://homepages.bluffton.edu/~nesterd/apps/slopefields.html Select the System tab.

Answer (score 0):

For the matrix of the Jacobian with inserted values of (x,y) at critical point:

\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}

If $\det A=0$, then all one can use to classify the CPs is the $a+b$ from the matrix above. If $a+b>0$, it is called a degenerated unstable node. If $a+b<0$, then it is called a degenerated stable node.